# Can't pass a constant variable by reference with $stmt->bind_param()?

Tags: php, mysqli, constants

This is my code snippet:

```
private function add_user_limit()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_limits` (user_ip, downloads_left) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $this->user_ip, DEFAULT_USER_LIMIT);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows == 0)
        throw new Exception("Couldn't add new user to the user_limits table");
    $stmt->close();
    $this->downloads_left = DEFAULT_USER_LIMIT;
}
```

`DEFAULT_USER_LIMIT` is defined as `8`, but with the above code I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\limits.class.php on line 38
```

But if I do this:

```
private function add_user_limit()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_limits` (user_ip, downloads_left) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $user_limit = DEFAULT_USER_LIMIT; // For some reason we can't pass a constant to bind_param
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $this->user_ip, $user_limit);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows == 0)
        throw new Exception("Couldn't add new user to the user_limits table");
    $stmt->close();
    $this->downloads_left = DEFAULT_USER_LIMIT;
}
```

It works. I was just wondering why this happens, as it doesn't really make sense to me. I don't see any reason why `bind_param()` can't take a constant variable as a parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: I applaud you for using parametrized queries. You are better than 99% of SQL developers in this respect. However, you may be taking things a bit too far here: There's no point in binding a constant as a parameter, because it's not user input. It's always going to be safe, unless you purposefully defined the constant to contain an SQL injection (for some reason). In short, just concatenate your constant into the query string directly. As for your question, the "reason" bind_param() can only take references is just a silly design limitation. There's no real "reason" for it. It just is what it is

Comment: The above notwithstanding, I was not trying to imply that there's *never* a reason for binding a constant.  Sorry if it seemed that way.  Legitimate reasons *could* include: better readability, better program flow, efficiency (sending less bytes to the SQL server), programmer preference.  Just that security is not a reason for binding a constant.  Cheers.

Comment: @Lakey Thanks for your comment. *There's no point in binding a constant as a parameter, because it's not user input. It's always going to be safe, unless you purposefully defined the constant to contain an SQL injection (for some reason). In short, just concatenate your constant into the query string directly* this line was answer for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, it's because you can't pass a constant by reference, and there would be no point in doing so, as it is immutable.  Constants, by the way, are not variables; it's right there in the name.

Comment: dont forget the SECOND purpose of passing by reference: avoiding moving large data... It does not have to be for editing, nicely seen in C++ where const references are frequently used as function params....

Comment: Yes, but this is PHP, which employs a "copy-on-write" mechanism, which means that, as long as you do not modify the value, you are effectively passing by reference at all times.  You can see this for yourself by writing scripts with large variables, then assigning copies, and checking the memory usage before and after modifying those copies.

Comment: I know and it does not change anything I've said :) , it just seemed you did not know the second purpose of passing by reference - this comment was for you, not for the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli's bind_param is defined like this:

```
bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

### Explanation

`&` means that variable is passed by reference and because constants (e.g.`DEFAULT_USER_LIMIT`) in PHP can not be referenced this way, they can only be passed as values because that's what they are.

So if you have a function that enforces passing by reference, first you must store the value of the constant to a variable and pass the variable (as you did...)

### Modern solution - just [use PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

If you can use PDO interface and don't need to pass values by reference,

**just use PDO**'s [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) + PDO in common cases is used almost the same way as Mysqli.

```
public bool PDOStatement::bindValue ( mixed $parameter , mixed $value [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR ] )
```

And if you'd still need to pass by reference, PDO also has a [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following things can be passed by reference:

- Variables, i.e. foo($a)
- New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
- References returned from function

No other expressions should be passed by reference, as the result is undefined

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

additionally,

mysqli_stmt_bind_param() requires parameters to be **passed by reference**, whereas call_user_func_array() can accept as a parameter a list of variables that can represent references or values.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php